# What's the effect of () on the simple code line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new at shell scripting. I have this code below and I don't know the difference between them. I searched for precedence operator (), and I couldn't figure it out what difference it makes on this line below.

```
stdbuf -o 0 -e 0 ../../<program> <input file> &> OutputFile.txt &

( stdbuf -o 0 -e 0 ../..<program> <input file> & ) &> OutputFile.txt
```

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Look for `subshell`.

Comment: It runs the enclosed command in a subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example runs `<program>` under `stdbuf` with standard output and standard error redirected to `OutputFile.txt` in the background (`&`).

The second runs `<program>` under `stdbuf` in the background (`&`) all in a subshell which has *its* standard error and standard output redirected to `OutputFile.txt`.

What the practical effects of this difference are, however, I can't say exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments, the `(...)` enclosed statements are executed in the `subshell`.

Imagine the following fragment:

```
echo 'line1' >  /tmp/file
echo 'line2' >> /tmp/file
echo 'line3' >> /tmp/file
```

using a subshell, you can redirect the whole subshell, so the above could be written as

```
(
echo 'line1'
echo 'line2'
echo 'line3'
) >/tmp/file
```

Both produces the same result, but the second is shorter, cleaner and easier modifiable.